# index.html not pulling in resources

Tags: html, express

I am setting up an express app, and using

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'))`

to serve my static files. But I'm not clear on what's exactly happening here. I thought this pointed any request to `/` to my `/public/views` directory, which is where I am storing my index.html file. And it does, because it loads up my index page. But then, from within my index.html file I am trying to pull in resources from `/public/lib` and those calls are failing.

Here is the relevant structure of my app

```
public/
    css/styles.css
    lib/'stuff im trying to get'
    views/index.html
```

And from within index.html I am trying this:

```
<link href="../css/styles.css">
<script src="../lib/path/to/resource">
```

So, as you can see, what I'm *trying* to do is jump out of my views folder, and hop into my css and lib folders, and pull in the resources. After a bit of finagling, I went into server.js and changed the static path to `__dirname + '/public'` which didn't help anything, until I moved my index.html file into the root of public. That served up everything nice and proper, which confused me a bit, because my scripts still had the `../` in front, which technically should have made me jump out of the public folder and into the root of my app. So then, just for kicks I changed my `../` to regular old `./` and everything was still okay.

Please if anyone has a couple of moments, would you mind explaining to me what I'm missing. I can't seem to come up with an explanation that accounts for everything.

Comment: In general you shouldn't put your `views` folder in `public`.  Stuff in public is directly readable by the outside world.  Views contain presentation logic that will be processed by express before being delivered.

Why are you trying to serve your view files statically?

Comment: "Why are you trying to serve your view files statically?". Because they might be static. Presentation does not have to be constructed server side. The ever growing AngularJS apps don't need this.

Comment: It is indeed an Angular app with client side templating, and I was only trying to serve my static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express serves the directory of static content in the root of your webserver, so '/public/views' appeared as '/' on the server. The referenced resources use the web path, not the filesystem path, so your references to '../lib/' could not get below the '/' directory.

When you made '/public' the web root, the css/js files were accessible via the web, and everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use relative urls like `../lib/relative.css`, or `lib/relative.css`, that causes unexpected behaviours such as,

if you are in a nested route like `localhost/home/index.html`, a relative url like `lib/relative.css` will result in `localhost/home/lib/relative.css`.

Use absolute urls, starting with a slash like `/lib/absolute.css` or `/../lib/absolute.css`, that causes to always return the resource from the base of the domain.

So in a nested route `localhost/home/index.html`, an absolute url `/lib/absolute.css`, will result in `localhost/lib/absolute.css`

This might not be a problem for serving static pages such as index.html, because you won't have index.html in nested routes, but it is a consideration for SPA's.

Answer (score 1):

In this case

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/views'))
```

your index.html is served when a request is made to '/'.

When the browser parses the HTML requested from '/' it tries to resolve the relative URLs in the HTML document. But since the HTML was served from '/' the browser doesn't know how to deal with URLs which start with '..', it therefor ignores the '..'. So the browser will make an request to "/css/styles.css" instead of "../css/styles.css". This translates to "__dirname/public/views/css/styles.css" on the server, which does not exists and a 404 is returned.

When you changed to

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
```

and placed the index.html into "/public" then the '..' in your links will still ignored by browsers. But now "/css/styles.css" can actually be resolved on the server side since "/public/css/styles.css" does exist.

So in this cause it is the browser who is the origin of the confusion (as always).